# No Choose Process option is there in trigger menu

Tags: g1ant

There no option of Choose process window in the Trigger menu even I have tried ctrl+G but it shows "No Process to Run". What to do?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to launch scripts from "Run process" window (Ctrl+G), you need to have them saved in Documents\G1ANT.Robot folder so that they appear in the list of processes to run.

[image]